# How to delete all white space during save except for final new line

Tags: whitespace, newlines

I am aware that it is a good idea to have one blank line at the end of each file.  I am also aware that extra white space in a file is bad.  Currently in my .emacs file I have `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)`  so that whitespace is removed during saving.

However, despite what [the wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeletingWhitespace#toc3) says, this also deletes the final newline from my file.

I tried setting `'(require-final-newline (quote visit-save))` but that had no effect.

Is there a way that I can force a newline to be added and all other extra whitespace removed?

Comment: I always try to steer people away from this idea, because it's so awful as soon as version control is involved. I suggest instead that you use one of the `ws-trim` or `ws-butler` libraries to ensure that *lines you edit* do not have trailing whitespace. You can always call `delete-trailing-whitespace` manually if you genuinely want to do this to a given file.

Comment: Do you have a preference between the two?

Comment: I use `ws-trim` due to inertia (it's been around much longer), but I think `ws-butler` has had some good improvements since it first appeared, and is possibly the better option, so I'd suggest trying that one first.

Comment: Uh, could  you help me enable butler mode by default?

Comment: Sure. If you `package-install` it from MELPA and then put `(ws-butler-global-mode 1)` in your init file, it looks like it should be enabled for all buffers. If you only want it for programming, start with `(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'ws-butler-mode)` instead, as the majority of programming modes are derived from `prog-mode`.

Comment: Thanks @phils How did you learn this? I looked at the readme and had no idea that I was supposed to prefix it with `ws`.  Additionally, when using `M-x Butler` I now have `Butler-status` and have no idea what that does - do you? It seems to only show an empty buffer.

Comment: I looked at the code rather than the readme. The commentary points out the `add-hook` approach, and I noticed the globalized mode when I skimmed through the elisp. The readme could use some work, certainly. I don't know what `M-x Butler` is, however. You may have installed something completely different!